# UWP GridView ItemTemplateSelector in SemanticZoom not applying

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, datatemplateselector

I have a GridView as my zoomed out view in a SemanticZoom control. This GridView uses a custom DataTemplateSelector as the ItemTemplateSelector. The DataTemplateSelector returns a DataTemplate with different Foreground color, depending upon whether or not the Group has any items in it.

However, even though the DataTemplateSelector seems to work and returns the correct template, only one template is ever used by the GridView and the text is all the same color.

Here is the XAML of the GroupedListView:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="GroupList.GroupList.GroupedListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GroupList.GroupList"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:GroupList.Model"
    xmlns:wuxdata="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Data"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- Use a collection view source for content that presents itself as a list of items that can be grouped or sorted.  Otherwise, you can use x:Bind
        directly on the ListView's item source to for further optimization. Please see the AppUIBasics sample for an example of how to do this.  -->
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsCVS"  IsSourceGrouped="True" />

        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TileHeaderTextStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ProximaNovaSemiBold}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="54" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontStretch" Value="Expanded" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TileHeaderTextStyleGray" BasedOn="{StaticResource TileHeaderTextStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Khaki" />
        </Style>

        <!-- When using x:Bind, you need to set x:DataType -->
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ContactListViewTemplate" x:DataType="data:Contact">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2"
                         Width ="32"
                         Height="32"
                         Margin="6"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         Fill="LightGray"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{x:Bind Name}" 
                           x:Phase="1"  
                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                           Margin="12,6,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{x:Bind Position}" 
                            x:Phase="2"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="12,0,0,6"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GrayZoomedOutTemplate" x:DataType="wuxdata:ICollectionViewGroup">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Group.(data:GroupInfoList.Key)}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Style="{StaticResource TileHeaderTextStyleGray}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedOutTemplate" x:DataType="wuxdata:ICollectionViewGroup">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Group.(data:GroupInfoList.Key)}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Style="{StaticResource TileHeaderTextStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:GroupEmptyOrFullSelector x:Key="GroupEmptyOrFullSelector" Empty="{StaticResource GrayZoomedOutTemplate}" Full="{StaticResource ZoomedOutTemplate}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <!--#region Navigation Panel -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="Paula's SemanticZoom Sandbox" Grid.Row="0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
            <Button x:Name="ZoomInOutBtn" Content="ABC↕" Click="ZoomInOutBtn_Click" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <!--#endregion-->
        <SemanticZoom x:Name="ZoomControl" Grid.Row="1">
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True">

                    <GridView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                                               Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </GridView.GroupStyle>
                </GridView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                <GridView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource GroupEmptyOrFullSelector}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Margin="0, 200" Width="475" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View.CollectionGroups}" SelectionMode="None" >
                </GridView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        </SemanticZoom>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the DataTemplateSelector:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using GroupList.Model;

namespace GroupList.GroupList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This determines whether or not the Group passed during binding is empty or not and allows selection
    /// of the proper DataTemplate based on this value.
    /// </summary>
    class GroupEmptyOrFullSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        private DataTemplate _full;
        private DataTemplate _empty;
        public DataTemplate Full
        {
            set { _full = value; }
            get { return _full; }
        }
        public DataTemplate Empty
        {
            set { _empty = value; }
            get { return _empty; }
        }


        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {

            var itemType = item.GetType();
            var isGroup = itemType.Name == "GroupInfoList";
            bool isEmpty = false;
            GroupInfoList groupItem;

            if (isGroup)
            {
                groupItem = item as GroupInfoList;
                isEmpty = groupItem.Count == 0;
            }

            // Disable empty items
            var selectorItem = container as SelectorItem;
            if (selectorItem != null)
            {
                selectorItem.IsEnabled = !isEmpty;
            }

            if (isEmpty)
            {
                return Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return Full;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks right. Have you checked your date source? Are you sure you have a empty group?

Comment: Yes, there are empty groups, I sat in the debugger and checked each one.

Answer (score 0):

So, here was the problem:

In the DataTemplateSelector listing, even if a passed "object item" was not a group, it fell through to the template selection logic.  Sometimes, the "object" passed to your function is not a Group object, but rather a generic DependencyObject.  In such a case, your template selection logic needs to return a default template, returning one of the specific templates only if the "object item" is a Group object.  Thus, the new function looks like this:

```
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {

        var itemType = item.GetType();
        var isGroup = itemType.Name == "GroupInfoList";
        bool isEmpty = false;
        GroupInfoList groupItem;

        if (isGroup)
        {
            groupItem = item as GroupInfoList;
            isEmpty = groupItem.Count == 0;

            // Disable empty items
            var selectorItem = container as SelectorItem;
            if (selectorItem != null)
            {
                selectorItem.IsEnabled = !isEmpty;
            }

            if (isEmpty)
            {
                return Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return Full;
            }

        }

        return Full;

    }
```

Comment: I can reproduce your issue now. And this answer also does not work.